# aspx dynamic data redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6

OK i have a .net site running on iis-7.5 and my forms are built from the database content. we have a form that was built and has answers attached to it and want to replace the form but not delete the old one so we created a new form, now my question is i am having an issue redirecting users from that form to the new form. here is what i have in the web.config file. and trying to redirect based on the `{QUERY_STRING}` but this does not seam to work, the old URL is still active. any help would be appreciated

```
<rewrite>

      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^http://www.oursite.com/service/ReportData\.aspx$" />
          <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^header=1393$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.oursite.com/service/ReportData.aspx?header=1395{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />

        </rule>

    </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

**EDIT 2:**

OK here is what i did and it works great.

I removed the domain from the equation and added `redirectType="Found"` so basically you must use folders for the redirect with a `{QUERY_STRING}`

```
<rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^service/ReportData\.aspx$" />

          <action type="Redirect" url="service/ReportData.aspx?header=1395" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />

          <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^header=1393$" />
          </conditions>

        </rule>
```

Comment: IIS 6.1? There is no such thing. What version of Windows is your server running?

Comment: Windows Web Server 2008 R2, And updated Post you are correct it is iis-7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is what i did and it works great.

I removed the domain from the equation and added redirectType="Found" so basically you must use folders for the redirect with a {QUERY_STRING}

```
<rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^service/ReportData\.aspx$" />

          <action type="Redirect" url="service/ReportData.aspx?header=1395" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />

          <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^header=1393$" />
          </conditions>

        </rule>
```